# javascript Regex for Absolute AND relative URl

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url-validation

Is there any regex which will validate both an absolute URL and relateve URl for Javascript.

I do have following Regex which works fairly well for absolute URL except the part where it is making the HTTP part mandatory. I want it optional.

Here is Regex:

```
/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/;
```

thanks

Comment: A relative URL can be basically anything, so you'd have a tough time validating that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

quick answer, modified Arun's answer to accept '/page', '/page/subpage', 'page/subpage'

```
/(\/?[\w-]+)(\/[\w-]+)*\/?|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)/gi
```

but in actually, validate the url with RegExp is never esay. lots of edge case, like './page', '../page' etc.

analyse your requirement carefully, write down the major test cases, write a RegExp pass them all. and be careful with performance.

Comment: For some reason javascript editor does not recognize this string as valid Regex.

Comment: whoops, I only posted the text part. should add `/` on each side. already updated the answer.

Comment: I actually did replace this new one with the old one and the problem here is that now it takes anything. It would also accept plain text as a valid URL :((

Comment: because I think "plain text" is also a valid **relative url**. example: `<a href="page_on_same_path">` or `<a href="sub/page_on_sub_path">`

Comment: This regex will match a single word character as well. Not exactly useful for validating relatively urls. Arun's solution below does not have the same issue.

Comment: This lets any string pass, e.g. abc, which I believe is not correct behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
/((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/;
```

It makes the `(http|ftp|https):\/\/` (http://) portion optional

Comment: Yes, it did make the HTTp part optional but still does not accept the relate path so it does acceprt www.google.com but it does not accept \page

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
/^(https?:\/\/|\/)\w+\.[^\s]+$|^\/[^\s]*$/
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

This one accepts things like:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com.com
/mypage
/my/page/
```

But not things like

```
httpa://example.com
my/page/
www
```

The regexp is:

```
/(^(https?:\/\/|\/)(?:www\.|(?!www))?[^\s])/
```

Comment: Your regex only matches the first character after `https://` or `http://` or `/`.