# Javascript url validation allowing relative and absolute urls

Tags: javascript, regex, url-validation

I'm trying to validate a field to allow relative and absolute urls. I'm using the regex from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720940/javascript-regex-for-absolute-and-relative-url) but it is allowing spaces in the url.

```
var urlRegex = new RegExp(/(\/?[\w-]+)(\/[\w-]+)*\/?|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)/gi);
```

Example:

```
// this should work
this/will/work.aspx?say=hello 
http://www.example.com/this/will/work.aspx?say=hello

// this shouldn't work but does
and/this will also work/even though it shouldn't
and/this-shouldn't/but it does/also
```

The code below is what I was originally using to validate just absolute urls and it was working perfectly. If I remember properly, I pulled it from the jquery source. If this could be modified to also accept relative urls that would be perfect, but this is out of my league.

```
var urlRegex = new RegExp(/^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i);
```

Comment: You don't need to be calling the RegExp constructor at all in these examples.

Comment: you're saying I can just do this... `var urlRegex = /.../;` right?

Comment: Yes - hold on I think I have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an article about URI validation complete with code snippets for all the various URI components as defined by [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) here:

[Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)

You may find what you are looking for there. Note however that almost any string represents a valid URI - even an empty string!

Comment: I'm looking at the path regex but I'm having trouble getting that to syntactically work in javascript. http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html#uri-34

Comment: @bflemi3 - Double-click on the regex in the article and a textbox containing a properly formatted code snippet pops up. You can chose the Javascript syntax via the drop-down menu. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to anchor the pattern so that it has to match the whole string:

```
var urlRegex = /^(\/?[\w-]+)(\/[\w-]+)*\/?|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)$/gi;
```

The leading `^` and trailing `$` means that the pattern has to match the entire string instead of just some part of it.

*edit* that said, the pattern has other problems. First, those HTML entities for `&` (`&amp;`) need to be just "&".  The slashes don't need to be escaped in `[]` groups, and we don't need the "g" suffix. That leaves us with:

```
var urlRegex = /^(?:(\/?[\w-]+)(\/[\w-]+)*\/?|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?))$/i;
```

*edit again* - oops also need to wrap the whole thing.

Comment: I've updated the pattern. Parsing URLs with regular expressions is kind-of tricky.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, it's almost there. It won't allow `/another/url.aspx` but it will allow `another/urls.aspx` as well as absolute urls. Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Well I think the issue is that the grouping is a little off. The "/another/url.aspx" part doesn't work because the left-hand part of the regex doesn't allow the ".aspx", while the right side does. However, the right side doesn't allow the leading slash. I think what we need is something like the right-hand part that matches the protocol and host, and then make that whole group be optional before the first "/", and then *that* whole group can be optional too (for "foo/bar.aspx").